# Inequality in 5 variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, examples-counterexamples

Let 5 positive real variables $(a,b,c,d,e)$. Prove or disprove:
$$
\sum_{cyc} a^2 b d (c+e)\ge \sum_{cyc} a b c e (a+d)
$$
where $\sum_{cyc}$ means all 5 cyclic shifts $(a,b,c,d,e) \to (b,c,d,e,a) \to$ etc.  Equality occurs if all 5 variables are equal, and it appears that equality occurs at no other points. I couldn't find counterexamples through simulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b(cd+de-ce)\geq5abcde.$$
We can take $a\rightarrow+\infty$ and $cd+de-ce<0.$

For example, take $(a,b,c,d,e)=(100,1,2,1,3).$

Now, we see that this inequality is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I need to check the arithmetic, but try $(a,b,c,d,e)=(2,3,1,2,10)$.

LHS$=2036$ and RHS$=2096$.