# Inequality in 5 variables with conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let 5 positive real variables $(a,b,c,d,e)$. These variables obey the conditions $a-b+c-d+e > 0$ and all 5 cyclic shifts thereof. This question is  tighter than [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3037214/).

Prove:
$$
\sum_{cyc} a^2 b d (c+e)\ge \sum_{cyc} a b c e (a+d)
$$
where $\sum_{cyc}$ means all 5 cyclic shifts $(a,b,c,d,e) \to (b,c,d,e,a) \to$ etc.  Equality occurs if all 5 variables are equal, and it appears that equality occurs at no other points. I couldn't find counterexamples through simulations.

Comment: It would be interesting to know where that problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The hint.

Let $a=x+y$, $b=y+z$, $c=z+t$, $d=t+w$ and $e=w+x$.

Thus, the condition gives that $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ and $w$ are positives and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(x+y)^2(y+z)(t^2+w^2+zt+tw+wx-zx)\geq5\prod_{cyc}(x+y),$$ which we can prove by BW:

Let $x=\min\{x,y,z,t,w\}$, $y=x+p$, $z=x+q$, $t=x+r$ and $w=x+s.$

Practically it's better to use the last substitution for the starting inequality:
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b(cd+de-ce)\geq5abcde.$$ 
Id est, let $a=x+u,$ $b=x+u+v$, $c=x+v+w$, $d=x+w+p$ and $e=x+p$,

where $x>0$ and $u$, $v$, $w$ and $p$ are non-negatives.

Comment: Here is the result for $\sum_{cyc}a^2b(cd+de-ce)- 5abcde \geq 0 $ with BW and it doesn't look to me like it it easy to prove that it is nonnegative

Comment: $p^3*u*v + p^3*u*w + p^3*u + p^3*v^2 + p^3*v*w + 2*p^3*v + p^3*w + p^3 + p^2*u^3 - 2*p^2*u^2*v - 2*p^2*u^2*w - 2*p^2*u*v^2 - 3*p^2*u*v + p^2*u*w^2 + p^2*v^2*w + p^2*v*w^2 + 3*p^2*v*w + p^2*v + p^2*w^2 + 2*p^2*w + p^2 + p*u^3*w + 2*p*u^3 + p*u^2*v^2 - p*u^2*v*w - 2*p*u^2*v - 2*p*u^2*w^2 - 3*p*u^2*w + p*u^2 + p*u*v^3 - p*u*v^2*w - p*u*v*w^2 - 3*p*u*v*w - 4*p*u*v - 2*p*u*w^2 - 4*p*u*w - p*u + p*v^3 - p*v + u^3*w + u^3 + u^2*v^2 + u^2*v*w^2 + u^2*w^3 + u^2 + u*v^3 + u*v^2*w^2 + 2*u*v^2 + u*v*w^3 + 3*u*v*w^2 + 2*u*w^3 + u*w^2 - u*w + v^3 + v^2*w^2 + v^2 + v*w^3 + 2*v*w^2 + w^3 + w^2$

Comment: @Andreas It should be homogeneous inequality of degree five, which says that there is a mistake in your computations (I have no some software and If you just wish I can calculate by hand. But it's better- no :)) You must get $A(u,v,w,p)x^3+B(u,v,w,p)x^2+C(u,v,w,p)x+D(u,v,w,p)\geq0$, where $A$ is a homogeneous second degree polynomial,  $B$ is a homogeneous third degree polynomial,  $C$ is a homogeneous fourth degree polynomial and  $D$ is a homogeneous fifth degree polynomial. It seems  that we'll get $A\geq0,$ $B\geq0$, $C\geq0$ and $D\geq0.$ Maybe did you put $x=1$? If so, we are done!

Comment: You're right, I put x= 1. Here is the result with free x:
$x^3(p^2 - pu - pv + u^2 - uw + v^2 + w^2) 
+ x^2(p^3 + p^2v + 2p^2w + pu^2 - 4puv - 4puw + u^3 + 2uv^2 + uw^2 + v^3 + 2vw^2 + w^3) 
+ x(p^3u + 2p^3v + p^3w - 3p^2uv + 3p^2vw + p^2w^2 + 2pu^3 - 2pu^2v - 3pu^2w - 3puvw - 2puw^2 + pv^3 + u^3w + u^2v^2 + uv^3 + 3uvw^2 + 2uw^3 + v^2w^2 + vw^3)
 + p^3uv + p^3uw + p^3v^2 + p^3vw + p^2u^3 - 2p^2u^2v - 2p^2u^2w - 2p^2uv^2 + p^2uw^2 + p^2v^2w + p^2vw^2 + pu^3w + pu^2v^2 - pu^2vw - 2pu^2w^2 + puv^3 - puv^2w - puvw^2 + u^2vw^2 + u^2w^3 + uv^2w^2 + uvw^3
$

Comment: Using  $pu \le \frac12 (p^2 + u^2)$ etc.,  the first polynomial is $A \ge \frac12 (v^2 + w^2) \ge 0$. The next ones $B, C, D$ get more complicated.

Comment: @Andreas I proved that $B\geq0.$

Comment: I proved that $B \ge 0$ as well. Here it is: Using $2pv \le p^2 + v^2$ and $2pu \le p^2 + u^2$ we have
$B \ge p^3 +p^2v + 2p^2w +pu^2 - 2(p^2+v^2)u - 2(p^2+u^2)w +u^3 + 2uv^2 +uw^2 +v^3 + 2vw^2 +w^3$
which is
$B \ge p^3 -2p^2u + p^2v +pu^2 +u^3 - 2u^2w  +uw^2 +v^3 + 2vw^2 +w^3$
which is 
$B \ge p(p-u)^2 + p^2v  +u(u-w)^2  +v^3 + 2vw^2 +w^3 \ge 0$